# Inheritance constructors: Converting from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm coming from a C# background where I would write a class and constructor like this:

```
public class Grunt : GameObject
{
    public Grunt()
        : base()
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

How do I write the constructors inheritance in C++? In both the header and the source. I know you don't have the 'base' keyword to work with, but otherwise is the syntax the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Grunt : public GameObject
{
    Grunt()
        : GameObject()  // Since there are no parameters to the base, this line is actually optional.
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

And strongly consider getting one of the fine C++ books at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `In both the header and the source.`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, replace `: base()` with `: GameObject()`.

But if there are no parameters the call is implied, as in C#

Answer (score 3):

You use the name of the base class in place of the 'base' keyword.  This is necessary because of the possibility for multiple inheritance in C++.  In the event of multiple base classes, you can call multiple base constructors by comma-delimiting the calls.

Answer (score 1):

header:

```
template <int unique>
class base { 
public: 
    base();
    base(int param);
};

class derived: public base<1>, public base<2> {
public:
    derived();
    derived(int param);
};
```

source:

```
base::base() 
{}

base::base(int param) 
{}

derived::derived() 
: base<1>()
, base<2>() 
{}

derived::derived(int param) 
: base<1>(param)
, base<2>(param) 
{}
```

This clarifies how to inherit from multiple classes, inherit from template classes, construct base classes, shows how to pass parameters to base constructors, and shows *why* we have to use the name of the base.